# Configure Teamcity to build a published website with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, teamcity

How does one configure the teamcity build process to produce the same compilation result as if I told Visual Studio to publish a website from Visual Studio?

basically, I need teamcity to build the website with a publishable package...then publish the package as an artifact, which I can then deploy on AWS using command line commands.

Is it possible? What are the command line MSBuild parameters necessary to get Visual Studio to spit out what I am looking for, and what would I need to match in the build output in order to publish the package? Currently, the website is too big for me to publish everything as an artifact, so I'm having trouble figuring out what to match for artifact publishing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build target WebPublish - that's what VS does when you select web project and publish it from context menu.